# subset dataframe using grep

Tags: r, regex, subset

I have dataframe named SCC in which one of the columns is EI.Sector. I would like to subset the data frame based on the condition:

```
grepl(".*Coal.*", SCC$EI.Sector)
```

So, I pass the command:

```
subset(subset=grepl(".*Coal.*", SCC$EI.Sector), SCC)
```

but I get an error saying ---Error in SCC$EI.Sector : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors. It works on a dataframe that was posted in this forum:

```
x <- c("G448", "G459", "G479", "G406")
y <- c(1:4)
My.Data <- data.frame (x,y)
> subset(subset=grepl("G45.*", My.Data$x), My.Data)
   x y
2 G459 2
```

Can someone tell me why this is happening? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to look at the `class` of your dataset.  I would suspect it as `table` or `matrix`.  For example:

```
 My.Data1 <- as.matrix(My.Data)
 subset(subset=grepl("G45.*", My.Data1$x), My.Data1)
#Error in My.Data1$x : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Also, `[` would be faster than `subset`

```
  My.Data[grepl("G45.*", My.Data$x),]
  #    x y
 #2 G459 2
```